# Python file does not recognize imported functions from other Python files

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my code more organized by creating separate files for various functions. I'm testing out printing scenes of dialogue with a text scrolling code, and instead of keeping every line of dialogue in one file, I have moved it to a `scene0.py` file in the folder `scenes`. In that file, I define the function `playscene0`.

In a different folder called `scenetext`, I have a file called `textstuff.py` which contains the defined functions `print_italics` (which prints italics text), `texttype` (which makes each character type out individually like some video games do), and `textscroll` (which reads lists of dialog and formats it, plus timings with `time.sleep`).

That aforementioned `scene0.py` file uses `from scenetext.textstuff import *` to import the above functions, plus additional variables that go along with them (unique to that file). VSCode seems to initially recognize that all the functions being used in the `playscene0` function have been successfully imported.

In my `importtest` file:

```
from scenes.scene0 import playscene0

playscene0()
```

This gives me:

```
NameError: name 'print_italics' is not defined
```

Though it very much is defined in the file it is derived from.

I've already looked into circular imports and how they cause problems, but that doesn't seem to be the cause here. I've tried importing both `time` and everything from `scenetext.textstuff` in the `importtest` file directly, but the problem persists.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you

EDIT: After adding `from scenetext.textstuff import print_italics` to the `importtest` file, it gives me a different error upon running:
ImportError: cannot import name 'print_italics' from 'scenetext.textstuff' (/Users/[me]/vscode/VOYAGE/scenetext/textstuff.py)

Not sure what causes this.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I restarted my computer and now it's working. Very strange. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an import to the importtest file - `from scenetext.textstuff import print_italics`, so that the function becomes "visible".

Answer (score 0):

You should import the **textstuff** functions BEFORE you import the **playscene** function that uses them

```
from scenetect.textstuff import print_italics
from scenes.scene0 import playscene0
playscene0()
```